# Получение HWND процесса без названия

Tags: c, windows, winapi

У программы может быть совершенно разные названия  (Например, "file1.txt - notepad.exe", "file2.txt - notepad.exe"), как мне получить HWND процесса в таком случае?

Comment: А **что** вы знаете о процессе? **Какого** процесса HWND вы хотите получить?

Comment: По классу окна, если класс окна не меняется при каждом запуске.

Comment: Вообще мне надо получить pid окна, его можно получить используя GetWindowThreadProcessId(), но название окна постоянно меняется при запуске и получить HWND я не могу.

Comment: Ну, на худой конец — `EnumWindows`, которая передает функции обратного вызова все HWND по очереди, а для каждого можно найти имя класса через `GetClassName` и сравнить с искомым...